# Placing one image on landing page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, loops

I have a gallery page that displays a variety of cards containing pets, inside each card is a full post with multiple pictures and details about a specific pet. My question is, on the gallery page, where the small cards are, I'd like there to be a thumbnail that shows one image from inside the full card so that users have an idea what the pet looks like ahead of time instead of forcing them to actually open the card to see the details and images.

```
                <div class="card" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-duration="1200">
                      <!-- spot where image should go -->
                    <h1><%=post.name %></h1>
                    <span><%=post.fee %></span>
                    <span><%=post.description %></span>
                    <span><%= post.location%></span>  
                    <div><a href="/gallery/pet/<%=post.id %>">View More</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Below is code from the show page of the card containing the full array of images:

```
    <% post.images.forEach(function(image) { %>
        <img src="<%=image.url %>" alt="Turtle Image" >

    <% }) %>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue/question?

Comment: I need to know how to take one image from the pet show page and display it on the gallery page as a thumbnail.